# ConvertFrom-Sting Template Parsing Failure with Array

Tags: string, powershell

It seems I'm overlooking something easy, but I continue to error out on several different approaches to parse a text file. (In the code below, I use a text variable instead of file.) What am I missing?

The text to parse (simulating a TXT data file) is:

```
$testText = @'

FolderName User                  AccessRights                                            
---------- ----                  ------------                                            
Calendar   Mickey Mouse          {Reviewer}                                              
Calendar   Donald Duck           {AvailabilityOnly}                                      
Calendar   Minnie Mouse-Ears     {Editor}                                                
Calendar   Scrooge McDuck        {Editor}                                                
Calendar   Pluto B. Dog          {LimitedDetails}                                        
Calendar   Roscoe Pico Train     {Reviewer}                                              
Calendar   Uncle Boss Hogg       {ReadItems, EditOwnedItems, EditAllItems, FolderVisible}



FolderName                             User                  AccessRights
----------                             ----                  ------------
{A9E2BC46-B3A0-4243-B315-60D991004455} Mickey Mouse          {None}      
{A9E2BC46-B3A0-4243-B315-60D991004455} Donald Duck           {None}      
{A9E2BC46-B3A0-4243-B315-60D991004455} Pluto B. Dog          {None}      



FolderName   User                  AccessRights
----------   ----                  ------------
GAL Contacts Mickey Mouse          {None}      
GAL Contacts Donald Duck           {None}      
GAL Contacts Minnie Mouse-Ears     {None}      
GAL Contacts Pluto B. Dog          {None}      



'@
```

The template I've attempted (with many variations) is the following:

```
$template = @'

FolderName User            AccessRights
---------- ----            ------------
{[string]Folder*:Calendar}   {[string]User:Mickey Mouse} {[array]FolderPermissions:{Reviewer}}
'@
```

Finally, the command executed would be:

```
$testText | ConvertFrom-String -TemplateContent $template -OutVariable sharedMailboxPermissions | Out-Null
```

The error comes out as:

**ConvertFrom-String : The supplied template was invalid: Characters of a name must be letters, digits, or underscores at line 4 column 94 while processing Span starting at line 4 column 84.**

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your text file looks like powershell objects piped to `Format-Table`...  How are the files being generated?  Your template is invalid because of this- `:{Reviewer}`

Comment: I can't confirm whether it works as I am on holidays but you might want to try: `$testText | `[`ConvertFrom-SourceTable`](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/ConvertFrom-SourceTable)

Answer (score 3):

Curly braces should be escaped. Following should work:

```
$testText | ConvertFrom-String -TemplateContent @'
{Folder*:Calendar} {User:Mickey Mouse} {FolderPermissions:\{Reviewer\}}
{Folder*:Calendar} {User:Uncle Boss Hogg} {FolderPermissions:\{ReadItems, EditOwnedItems, EditAllItems, FolderVisible\}}
{Folder*:\{A9E2BC46-B3A0-4243-B315-60D991004455\}} {User:Mickey Mouse} {FolderPermissions:\{None\}}
'@
```

**Result**

```
Folder                                 User                       FolderPermissions                                       
------                                 ----                       -----------------                                       
Calendar                               Mickey Mouse               {Reviewer}                                              
Calendar                               Donald Duck                {AvailabilityOnly}                                      
Calendar                               Minnie Mouse-Ears          {Editor}                                                
Calendar                               Scrooge McDuck             {Editor}                                                
Calendar                               Pluto B. Dog               {LimitedDetails}                                        
Calendar                               Roscoe Pico Train          {Reviewer}                                              
Calendar                               Uncle Boss Hogg            {ReadItems, EditOwnedItems, EditAllItems, FolderVisible}
{A9E2BC46-B3A0-4243-B315-60D991004455} Mickey Mouse               {None}                                                  
{A9E2BC46-B3A0-4243-B315-60D991004455} Donald Duck                {None}                                                  
{A9E2BC46-B3A0-4243-B315-60D991004455} Pluto B. Dog               {None}                                                  
GAL                                    Contacts Mickey Mouse      {None}                                                  
GAL                                    Contacts Donald Duck       {None}                                                  
GAL                                    Contacts Minnie Mouse-Ears {None}                                                  
GAL                                    Contacts Pluto B. Dog      {None}
```

Comment: This is really close but is getting tripped on the "GAL Contacts" lines. Impressive though, I'm surprised it was workable at all with the input given!

Comment: I missed that. I wonder if auto-template is able to find split in `GAL Contacts Donald Duck`. It can be matched as `GAL` `Contacts Donald Duck`, `GAL Contacts` `Donald Duck` and `GAL COntacts Donald` `Duck`.

Answer (score 0):

The specific error you are seeing above is because you are using curly braces in your match. You can get around that by escaping it with `\` I think, but I don't think doing so necessarily makes your code work fully.

Unfortunately I think your input file is too complex/varied in structure to be handled by `ConvertFrom-String`. However here's an alternative solution that uses some regular expressions and splitting of strings to get the output I think you need:

```
$UserIndex = 0
$AccessIndex = 0

$Results = ForEach ($Line in $testText -split "`n") {

    If ($Line -match '^FolderName') {
        $UserIndex = $Line.IndexOf('User')
        $AccessIndex = $Line.IndexOf('AccessRights')
    }

    If ($Line -notmatch '^FolderName|^$|^---------') {
       [PSCustomObject]@{
            FolderName   = $Line.SubString(0,$UserIndex).Trim()
            User         = $Line.SubString($UserIndex,($AccessIndex - $UserIndex)).Trim()
            AcccssRights = $Line.SubString($AccessIndex).Trim()
       }
    }
}

$Results
```

This loops through the text one line at a time and looks for a line that starts with "FolderName". If it finds this line, it looks for "User" and "AccessRights" within that line and captures the index that those strings appear at.

We then use that Index to find the data within the subsequent lines. There is another regex here that filters out the lines that start "FolderName", empty lines (by using RegEx `$^`) and lines that start "---------". If its not one of those lines, then we return a PowerShell Object with the properties for each piece of data, which we find by working with the indexes we earlier identified.

Beware this works with the input you provided, but it makes a number of assumptions that the data will always be this way.

Per the comments, it does look like your original file is being output by PowerShell somewhere using the default `Format-Table` type view. It would of course be easiest to change the output at source to something easier to handle (e.g Export-CSV).

Answer (score 0):

- The curly braces in your template referring to your sample data have to be escaped with a backslash `\{Reviewer\}`
- You'll need more than one sample line when using the `*` and complex differing sample data, see [this link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2014/10/31/convertfrom-string-example-based-text-parsing/)

with this template:

```
$template = @'

FolderName User            AccessRights
---------- ----            ------------
{[string]Folder*:Calendar}   {[string]User:Mickey Mouse} {[string]FolderPermissions:\{Reviewer\}}
{[string]Folder*:Calendar}   {[string]User:Uncle Boss Hogg}       {[string]FolderPermissions:\{ReadItems, EditOwnedItems, EditAllItems, FolderVisible\}}                                      
'@

$testText | ConvertFrom-String -TemplateContent $template
```

I get this sample output:

```
Folder   User              FolderPermissions
------   ----              -----------------
Calendar Mickey Mouse      {Reviewer}
Calendar Donald Duck       {AvailabilityOnly}
Calendar Minnie Mouse-Ears {Editor}
Calendar Scrooge McDuck    {Editor}
Calendar Pluto B. Dog      {LimitedDetails}
Calendar Roscoe Pico Train {Reviewer}
Calendar Uncle Boss Hogg   {ReadItems, EditOwnedItems, EditAllItems, FolderVisible}
```

My own experiences with cfs are quote mixed, I don't know if it is possible to grab all three variants of your test data with one template. (And arrays at all)

Adding more template lines to properly get all variants leads to errors.